# C: Size of array changes scanf

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, c-strings

I'm trying to understand, why does the size of array change the output (input is `10 5`). If I set `char k[1]` then it only prints `5`, but if I set `char k[2]` then if prints `10 5`.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char n[10 ^ 1000];
    char k[1];

    scanf("%s%s", n, k);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(n); i++) {
        printf("%d", n[i] - '0');
    }

    printf(" %d", k[0] - '0');
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `10^1000` is `994`. Is that what you expected?

Comment: `%s` stores a string. A string in C requires a NUL terminator. So `char k[1]` is too small and the `scanf` will overflow that buffer resulting in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for your comment. Could you please explain why ```10^1000``` is ```994```? I would like to create an array of a size ```10^1000```.

Comment: The caret operator is the bitwise xor operator.

Comment: @SupportUkraine thanks for the comment. Should I use calloc or malloc?

Comment: To expand on what @SupportUkraine wrote: `pow(10,1000)` is `1` followed by `1000` zeroes.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I'm solving a school exercise where input is integer n from the interval [1, 10^1000]. Because it's bigger than long I decided to use an array to store the values. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @SupportUkraine thanks a lot, I get it now. I'll change it to n[1002].

Comment: @SupportUkraine thanks again. I changed `scanf` to `scanf("%s%1s", n, k);`

Comment: Joining late... It's thought that there are 10^82 atoms in the visible universe... 10^1000 won't fit... :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration

```
char n[10^1000];
```

there is used the bitwise exclusive OR operator ^.

From the C Standard (6.5.11 Bitwise exclusive OR operator)

> 4 The result of the ^ operator is the bitwise exclusive OR of the
> operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if
> exactly one of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is
> set).

So the above declaration is equivalent to

```
char n[994];
```

When a string is entered using the conversion specifier `s` then the function `scanf` stores also the terminating zero character `'\0'` in the destination character array.

As a result for this declaration

```
char k[1];
```

where there is no space for the terminating zero character `'\0'` the call of `scanf` overwrites memory beyond the array that results in undefined behavior.

As for your question then it is seems that the compiler placed the character array `n` just after the array `k`. So the terminating zero character is written in the first character of the array `n` when the array `k` is declared as shown above with one element and after the call of `scanf` you have in fact in the memory occupied by the arrays the following

```
k[0] = '5';
n[0] = '\0';
```

That is the array `n` stores an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As coded, your program has undefined behavior because `char k[1]` defines an array of size 1, which can only receive an empty string, which `scanf("%s"...)` cannot parse. The string typed will cause a buffer overflow: `scanf()` will attempt to store bytes beyond the end of the destination array.

You must pass the maxumum number of characters to store into the destination array before the null terminator.

Also note that `10^1000` used the xor operator and has the value `994`.

To output the ASCII values of the characters typed, just pass the `char` values directly with the format `%d`, they will be promoted to `int` implicitly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[100];

    if (scanf("%99s", s) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            printf("char at offset %d is `%c` (ASCII %d)\n", i, s[i], s[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char n[5]; 
     char k[5];

   int i;

    printf("input for char n is = ");
      scanf("%s", n);
 
      printf("input for char k is = ");
    scanf("%s", k);

     for (i=0; i<strlen(n); i++) 
    {
        printf("char n is = ");
       printf("%d \n", n[i] -'0');
    }

    printf("char k is = ");
    printf("%d \n", k[0] - '0');

}


// "for" loop initial declaration are allowed only on c99 or c11 mode.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).